# Is US citizenship and/or residence requirement for "accredited investor" status?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, start-up, funding

I've been reading about founders fund, and i'm wondering (since this is not listed anywhere in the documentation) - is it possible for a non-US resident or citizen to participate?

Comment: Residence and citizenship are different things. Could you please clarify if the title is correct or the body as these are slightly different things as there are US Citizens that live abroad while there are also US residents that aren't citizens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about the US, then according to the [SEC](http://www.investor.gov/news-alerts/investor-bulletins/investor-bulletin-accredited-investors) neither citizenship nor residency are a requirement.